# Android - Array into ImageView No Loop

Tags: java, android, arrays, loops, imageview

I have a main activity with a ListView for my array.
The array currently contains 4 items, (it will grow):

```
- <string-array name="ot_images">
   <item>"file:///android_res/drawable/ot_100.jpg"</item> 
   <item>"file:///android_res/drawable/ot_101.jpg"</item> 
   <item>"file:///android_res/drawable/ot_102.jpg"</item> 
   <item>"file:///android_res/drawable/ot_103.jpg"</item>
```

I want to show these images (1 by 1, swipe action, centered, no thumbnails) so after reaching the last one, it will come back to the Main Activity.

What would be the best approach?
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a view pager, you can customise it a little so when it will be at the last image you will close it.